# AirDrop doesnt work on Macbook Air 2012 and iPhone 6S

Tags: airdrop

I try to send content from iPhone to my Macbook Air via AirDrop. Everything seems to be correct. On both devices the bluetooth and same wifi is turned on. On both it is allowed **from Everyone**. But my mac is still invisible for my iPhone. Why?

Definitely sth is wrong with my macbook, because I can share between iOS devices, but cannot connect from and to my Macbook.

I know that AirDrop doesnt work with Macbook earlier than 2012, but my Macbook is 2012, so it should work. It is not duplicated question.

Comment: It is not duplicated question. It is obvious that airdrop works on 2012 and never macbook air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the development of Bluetooth 4.0 and BLE, it is not possible to airdrop between newer iOS devices and older (pre-retina, I believe) MacBooks.

This is because the standards are incompatible, while 'legacy airdrop' is still an option for MacBook-to-MacBook communication, it appears iOS devices do not have this functionality. A more in depth discussion can be found on Apple's [forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6601847?start=0&tstart=0), and a lengthy discussion on whether an upgrade is possible or should be attempted [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6401528?tstart=0).